# Bootstrap grid system, weird behavior

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

why is `class="col-12 col-md-auto"` doesn't work in bootstrap, I am expecting my `col` to be auto for medium devices and full width for x-small and small devices. But in reality seems like `col-12` is totally ignored, any suggestions please?

Comment: You might want to mention which version of bootstrap you're using. Make sure the documentation you're reading matches the version you're using.

Comment: sure, I am using bootstrap latest version 5.0

Comment: Can you provide a code example ? It will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it has nothing to do with the poor bootstrap, it's just a CSS conflict, another CSS file define also a breakpoint for the class .col-md-auto:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    /**/
    .col-md-auto {
        /**/
        width: auto !important;
        /**/
    }
}
```

this small important is the root of this issue, this is because inspecting CSS in dev tool is always a good idea.